# Resteasy FrameWork POST not working

Tags: rest, resteasy

I wish to use the interface only option of the RestEasy framework as it is much cleaner and should work.

But I'm having problems with passing parameters within POST request.

I found this example in the documentation:

```
@PUT
@Path("basic")
@Consumes("text/plain")
void putBasic(String body);
```

And to invoke:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ProxyFactory;
// ...

// this initialization only needs to be done once per VM
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

SimpleClient client = ProxyFactory.create(SimpleClient.class, "http://localhost:8081");
client.putBasic("hello world");
```

I've tried the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("http://localhost:8080/app/resource")
String postBasic(String body);
```

And invoked:

```
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

RepoClient client = ProxyFactory.create(RepoClient.class, "");
client.postBasic("hi");
```

When printing the parameters Map (and debugging it) on the `doPost` method of the called servelet, the parameters were empty. I really can't see the difference between my approach and the documented one (which is from here: [Resteasy interface example](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html)).

So to sum up, only using the Interface declaration and proxy implementation how can I send POST parameters?

Solution: It's as expected...just needed to declare the consumes accordingly with the received parameter and it works...the problem was calling the POST method of a servlet within another servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST example, the `@Path` cannot include an absolute URL. Try to put just `/app` or `/app/resource`, depending on your configuration.

Comment: Just tried...the servlet is actually called...but has no request parameters

Comment: Are you calling the server in a different executable? Note that you create a `ProxyFactory` with an *empty* base URL, so does it really connect through the network (even through loopback) to the server?

Comment: I'll check if invoking the post method within a servlet might be the issue

Comment: OK. You also can use any network sniffer like wireshark to see if you're really sending the package over the network.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but POST is so basic that it should support it :)

Answer (score 0):

As doubter said, @Path should be a relative url, I've only had experience with Jersey, and I'm not familiar with Resteasy, but I think this would be the same.

You class will have a @Path annotation, and the methods within can have a @Path annotation.

So if you had something like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path( "Foo" )     
    public class Foo()
    {
      @POST
      @Path( "Bar" )
      public String Bar()
      {
        ...
      }
    }
```

So a POST to http://localhost:8080/Foo/Bar will execute the method Bar.

My comment was getting long, so I'll just tack it here.

Sorry, I didn't see your comment on doubters post until after.  Does the example you're going off of use a @FormParam?

Given, I'm new to REST, but so far every @POST methods has had to use either @PathParam or @FormParam and your method would look like this:

```
    @Post
    @Path( "Foo/{foobar}" )
    public String Bar(@PathParam( "foobar" ) String foobar)
    {
    }
```

or like

```
    @Post
    @Path( "Foo" )
    public String Bar(@FormParam( "foobar" ) String foobar)
    {
    }
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the @Path...the post method in the servlet is called but the string parameter isn't passed to it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment on doubters post until after.  Does the example you're going off of use a @FormParam?

Comment: nop...take a look at the link I've posted...it's a simple post

Comment: I added some stuff in the edit, but I don't think that will help then.  I wonder if its something I haven't had to do yet, or if its a difference in Jersey and Resteasy?